# Not printing the last value from ECHO PHP

Tags: php, echo

the problem is I need to print the value coming from fgets(STDIN), in the follow manner:

```
INPUT - STRING
OUTPUT  ++++++++
        +STRING+
        ++++++++
```

Unlucky I had stuck, please check my code:

```
<?php
    echo "start!!\n";
    $input_line = fgets(STDIN);
    $input_nobreaks = str_replace("\n","",$input_line);
    $length = strlen($input_nobreaks);
    $x="+";
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($length + 1); $i++) {
        echo $x;
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo $x,$input_nobreaks,$x;
    echo "\n";
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($length + 1); $i++) {
        echo $x;
    }
    //echo "\n".$input_nobreaks;
    echo "\nend!!";
?>
```

Thank you for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: You should use $i <= $length instead of $i < ($length + 1). Anyway, the bucles seems right, it should return all values with your sintax. Maybe the strlen($input_nobreaks) return the length - 1, not the total length.

Comment: You can use `str_repeat($x, $length + 2)`. 2 because there is one '+' before and one '+' after.

Comment: ```+++++
+ooo
+++++ ```
this is my outcome now, I wish I can have +ooo+ when I am inputing `ooo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_repeat($x, $length + 2)`. 2 because there is one `+` before and one `+` after.

```
$input_line = "Hello\nworld!";
$input_nobreaks = str_replace(["\n", "\r"], '', $input_line);
$length = strlen($input_nobreaks);
$x = '+';

echo str_repeat($x, $length + 2) . "\n";
echo $x . $input_nobreaks . $x . "\n";
echo str_repeat($x, $length + 2) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
+++++++++++++
+Helloworld!+
+++++++++++++
```

See [`str_repeat()`](https://php.net/str_repeat).

NB: You could use `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()` in case of multibyte string.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it, but I still have the same problem. I have exchanged lines with loop, but still there is lack of last +
`
PS C:\Users\jakub\www> php test.php
start!!
000
+++++
+000
+++++

end!!
`

Comment: Please, see [this demo](https://3v4l.org/Fsmuu). Did you tried to replace `\r` too? `str_replace(["\n","\r"],"",$input_line)` - like [this](https://3v4l.org/cf2Hi).

Comment: Thank you Sir, but it doesn't work in my terminal, I don`t know why, that's weird. Thank you very much for your time. Maybe it is something with fgets ;(

Comment: I've tested using PowerShell and an Unix terminal. It works fine. Maybe a `trim()`?